# Matching nulls(0) in int [c++]

Tags: c++, windows, int

I have a problem with checking on 0, i trying to get numbers from file(and i get it) but if is 0 then said me >

```
0 maybe its not found!(0 | 0)   
0 maybe its not found!(1 | 1)   
0 maybe its not found!(2 | 2)   
0 maybe its not found!(3 | 3)   
0 maybe its not found!(4 | 4)
```

if i want 1 and i gets the correct line from line:

```
0 maybe its not found!(0 | 0)   
[Line0]: 1 1 1 200 150 6 1 10000000 1     
[Line1]: 1 1 13 14    
0 maybe its not found!(2 | 2)     
0 maybe its not found!(3 | 3)     
0 maybe its not found!(4 | 4)
```

Check func is :

```
int myClass = 0; //'\0'
for(int i=0; i < Show.line0 && Show.line1; i++)
{
    if( Show.Get[i].m_Class0 && Show.Get[i].m_Class1 == myClass )
    {
      ........
    }
    else
    {
        cout << myClass; cout << " maybe its not found!";
        cout << "(";
        cout << Show.Get[i].m_Class0; 
        cout << " | ";
        cout << Show.Get[i].m_Class1; 
        cout << ")"; 
        cout << endl;
    }
```

m_class0/1 are int and the value its getted from the loaded file.
in other value on myClass bigger then 0 i gets the same line lines from file begining with wanted number, but doesnt works with 0.

Comment: I think you want `if( Show.Get[i].m_Class0 == myClass && Show.Get[i].m_Class1 == myClass )`.

Comment: yes, now works... my head will bang :D
omg so simple it is :/

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll move it over if that's all it was.

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in the following line:

```
if( Show.Get[i].m_Class0 && Show.Get[i].m_Class1 == myClass )
```

Here, the compiler evaluates:

```
Show.Get[i].m_class0
```

If this is `true`, the compiler goes on to evaluate:

```
Show.Get[i].m_Class1 == myClass
```

If this is `true` (the other one must be true at this point, unless && was overloaded), then the `if` block executes.

The problem lies  within the first condition. It will be `true` when `Show.Get[i].m_Class0` does not equal 0.

What you really want is the opposite in this case (since `myClass` is 0):

```
if( Show.Get[i].m_Class0 == myClass && Show.Get[i].m_Class1 == myClass )
```

Now I mentioned a couple of things in there. The first is that the second part will only be evaluated if the first is `true`. This is called short circuit evaluation, and is used to save time. However, if one were to overload `operator&&`, the short circuit no longer kicks in. That is the second, and this is why it's generally a bad idea to do so, as it can give unexpected side effects from the second condition.

For example:

```
if (false && ++x)
```

would leave `x` if the && is native, but increment `x` if it is an overloaded version.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if( Show.Get[i].m_Class0 && Show.Get[i].m_Class1 == myClass )
> ```

As @chris commented, this is not doing what you seem to think.

`if (A && B == 0)` does not mean *"if A and B are both equal to zero"*

It means *"if A is true, and B is equal to zero"* and that fails when `A` is zero, because zero is `false`

You want `if (A == 0 && B == 0)` which means *"if A is equal to zero **and** B is equal to zero"*